# HTML Multidimensional input name for complex inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array, input

Selected items must have their discounts aligned with them.
I want to ignore the item if it is not selected.

This is my setup for my table of inputs.

```
item   |   amount   |   buy (yes, no)   |   discount( No Discount, 50%, 100%, 100.00 )
```

```
apple  |   100.00   |       yes         |   50%
```

```
banana |   500.00   |       no          |   0%
```

```
pie    |   250.00   |       yes         |   50%
```

```
<tr>
    <input name='item[]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
    <select name='discount[]' >
        <option value="1"> No discount </option>
        <option value="2"> 50% </option>
    </select>
</tr>
```

If I use `item[]` for the items and `discount[]` for the discount, my server will get:

```
item[ "1", "3"]
discount[ "2", "1", "2" ]
```

How could I connect the items to thier discount?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Solution: no js needed**

The formula for input `name` would be:

```
name="GROUP[ $GROUP_INDEX ]['FIELD_NAME']"
```

our html would be:

```
<tr>
    <input name='items[ $some_loop_index ]["item"]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
    <select name='items[ $some_loop_index ]["discount"]' >
        <option value="1"> No discount </option>
        <option value="2"> 50% </option>
    </select>
</tr>
```

On our server we will get:

```
"items": [
    {
        "'item'": "1",
        "'discount'": "2"
    },
    {
        "'discount'": "1"
    },
    {
        "'item'": "3",
        "'discount'": "2"
    }
]
```

The data is now grouped. :)